# Javascript 'Element must be a table' <table id="mytable">

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesort

I am using this tablesorter: https://github.com/tristen/tablesort

However, when I view this page I'm not able to sort the columns. Chrome dev tools shows `Uncaught Error: Element must be a table
    at new Tablesort (tablesort.js:6)
    at mytable.html:12`

I'm assuming this table:

```
<table id='mytable'>
```

and this code

document.getElementById('mytable')

are referencing the same 'mytable'. I've based that assumption on 'table-id' as shown here: http://tristen.ca/tablesort/demo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <script src='./src/tablesort.js'></script>
 <script src='./src/sorts/tablesort.number.js'></script>
 <script src='./src/sorts/tablesort.date.js'></script>
 <link href='./demo/style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
 <link href='tablesort.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
<body>
 <script> new Tablesort(document.getElementById('mytable')); </script>
 <table id='mytable' class="sort" border = "1">
 <thead>
 <tr>

  <th>Name</th>
  <th data-sort-method='number'>Age</th>
  <!-- <th>Age</th> -->
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Ramesh Raman</td>
  <td>22</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Shabbir Hussein</td>
  <td>32</td>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The table doesn't exist yet when you call `document.getElementById('mytable')`. See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: Three suggestions: 1) the demo .html templates all use `<table id='sort' class='sort'>`.  Perhaps you can try the same, and see if it works?  2) Debug the error by setting a breakpoint in Chrome Developer Tools, and work your way backwards to the solution.  ... AND ... 3) Move your Javascript to the *BOTTOM* of your file.

Comment: well, lets be honest, the error from that library could at least indicate that you didn't set a valid element, like an argument exception, but the info given here is ofcourse accurate :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because the script tag is loaded before the body. Put the code in a window.onload:

```
window.onload = function() {
    new Tablesort(document.getElementById('mytable'));
}
```

You could alternatively put the script tags at the bottom of the body, because it would be loaded last and therefore be able to find the table.

Comment: I have placed the <script> just before the close of body </body> and the error is gone. However I'm still unable to sort any columns.